# How to send signal from a children to another children in C?

Tags: c, signals, fork, pid

How can I send a signal form passenger-children to the taxi - children?
I have the following C code:

```
 passengerPid = fork()
 if(passengerPid) { //passenger-parents 

                taxiPid = fork();   
                if(taxiPid) { //taxi - parents      
                } else { //taxi - children  
                } 
        }       
        else { //passenger - children  
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How can I send a signal form passenger-children to the taxi - children?* **yes** it's possible but question here is how will you get `taxi-children` pid in `passenger-children` process ? once you got pid of that taxi-children, for sending signal to one process from another process you can use `kill()` function. Use any `IPC` mechanism to sending `pid`(any int data) of one process to other process.

Here is my Solution, before this go through man page of `wait()` & `waitpid()` :

```
/**How can I send a signal form passenger-children to the taxi - children? **/
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main() {
    int passengerPid, taxiPid;
    passengerPid = fork();
    if(passengerPid) { //passenger-parents 

        taxiPid = fork();   
        if(taxiPid) { 
            //taxi - parents   

            printf("taxi parents or main parent process : pid = %d ppid = %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            /** parents should wait until all children's got finish 
               use wait() or waitpid() to collect the children's status **/  
            int s,ret;
            while((ret = wait(&s))!=-1)//if there is no further child, wait returns 
            {
                if(ret == passengerPid) {
                    if(WIFEXITED(s)) {
                    printf("passenger children removed after sleep, status is : %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(s));
                    } else if(WIFSIGNALED(s)) {
                        printf("passenger children removed forcefully because of signal no : %d \n",WTERMSIG(s));
                    }
                } else if(ret == taxiPid) {
                    if(WIFEXITED(s)) {
                    printf("taxi children removed after sleep, status is : %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(s));
                    } else if(WIFSIGNALED(s)) {
                        printf("taxi children removed forcefully because of signal no : %d \n",WTERMSIG(s));
                    }

                }
            }
            printf("all done !! parents is also going to complete \n"); 
        } 
        else {
            //for sending pid of this process

        #if 0   
            int fd = open("data",O_WRONLY | 0664);
            if(fd == -1) {
                perror("open");
                return 0;
            }
            int w_pid = getpid();
            write(fd,&w_pid,4); 
            close(fd);
        #endif
            //taxi - children  
            printf("taxi children : pid = %d ppid = %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            sleep(10);//random delay to observe whether this process got any signal or not ?
            exit(1);//sends it's exit status to it's parent process whether it's terminated normally or by any external signal
        } 
    }       
    else { 
        //passenger - children  
        printf("passenger children : pid = %d ppid = %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        printf("sending signal from passenger children to taxi children :\n");
        sleep(5);   
        int pid;
    #if 0
        int fd = open("data",O_RDONLY | 0664);
        if(fd == -1) {
            perror("open");
            return 0;
        }
        read(fd,&pid,4);
        close(fd);
    #endif
        printf("pid of child received : %d \n",pid);
        kill(pid,SIGKILL);//sending signal no 2 to taxi child, bydefault action of SIGINT will be performed 
        perror("kill");
        printf("passenger children dies after sending signal & completion of delay\n");
        exit(0); 
    }
}
```

how above code works is explained in comments itself. usage of `macro(#if 0)` part in both process is for sending `pid` of that `taxi-child process` to `passenger-child process`. **Enable** the **macro** for observing the output.

I hope it help's.